# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to run a script to grab dada from an API and feed to a mongodb database. And I keep getting this error but if I test one sing url it works.

Any suggestions?

full script http://pastebin.com/Xap5vYYC

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hmsParser.py", line 112, in <module>
    smReply = urlopen(smUrl).read().decode("utf8")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
```

Comment: protip: use http://pastebin.com/ to post your script.

Comment: If you try the exact same URL by itself one time, it works?  You're __sure__ it's the exact same URL?  You're not just retyping it by hand?

Comment: When using the API, do _any_ of the requests work?  Perhaps the site is throttling requests by returning a 404 if you ask for too many?  When you try a single URL, are you doing it from the same computer?  How much time passes between the 404 and the successful request?

Comment: Yes I am retyping it by hand. So If I make the url manually, it works. Using the script it never works. So I know its something in the script and this site has previously returned many requests at a time.

Comment: Try editing your script to make `phaseOneIds` contain a single id, then see what happens.

Comment: Still got the same thing.

Comment: I simplified your script down to just a few lines [here](http://pastebin.com/xLiyhQ4q) and it worked for me.  Try it and see if it works for you.